# Get list of X minimum distances by their indices

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a huge matrix (think 20000 x 1000) called Z that I need to generate the pairwise distance from so I'm currently using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(Z,Z)` to generate the pairwise distances.

However, now I need to search through the result to find the smallest X distances but I need their indices.

An example would be:

```
A = 20000 x 1000 numpy.ndarray
B = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(A, A)
C = ((2400,100), (800,900), (29,999)) if X = 3
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I saw `numpy.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)` but I'm not sure it would work well for this instance.

Comment: scipy.spatial.distance.squareform

 converts pairwise distances to/from the condensed form.  One option is find the argmin in the condense form, and map that index back to an upper triangular array.  Search recent scipy questions for `pdist` and `squareform`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42098093/901925; http://stackoverflow.com/q/42046359/901925

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.triu_indices` to generate the indices that correspond to entries of the compressed distance matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

# Generate points
Z = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, 3))
# Compute euclidean distance
distance = pdist(Z)
# Get the smallest distance
min_distance = np.min(distance)
# Get the indices (k = 1 to omit diagonal entries)
idx = np.asarray(np.triu_indices(len(Z), 1))
# Filter the indices (this is assuming that the minimum distance is not unique)
idx = idx[:, distance == min_distance]
```

If you know that there is exactly one minimum distance, you could also use

```
idx = idx[:, np.argmin(distance)]
```

which is slightly more efficient.

**EDIT**: To get the sorted indices, try the following

```
idx = idx[:, np.argsort(distance)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wasn't working out for me. I need it to be sorted by the minimum pairwise distances and then get the indices of that sort.